# Learn which programming language is used in web service from url

Tags: xml, web-services

Is there any method to learn web service detail information from url?

for instance;

which programming language is used
which technology is used etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overarching protocol for all web services for determining programming language used or other such implementation details.

However, here are some resources for detecting and reporting on tech stacks in general used by a site:

- [Wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/): *a cross-platform utility that uncovers the
  technologies used on websites.*
- [BuiltWith](https://builtwith.com/): *Find out what websites are Built With*
- [Netcraft](https://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report): *Link to a detailed report about the site, helping you to make informed choices about their integrity.*

See also the list at [How to find What Technology Website using?](https://geekflare.com/what-technology-website-using/)

Comment: These are related with web sites but i wanna learn local web service information.

Comment: If it's local, why don't you just look at the source or ask the responsible party?

Comment: Answer updated to state explicitly that there is no overarching protocol for all web services for determining implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if a page is well structured in back- and frontend, it is impossible to tell.
You will probably have to get to know which CMS for example is used.

If, for example, you see IDs / Classes in the source code of the page, which have a "wp" prefix, then you know **Wordpress** is used in backend, and as Wordpress is based on php, you know the page runs on **php**.

If you see "sf" prefixes, it is highly likely that the page is based on **Sitefinity** CMS and therefore uses **ASP.NET MVC** as technology stack and using **C#** as language and uses **JavaScript**.

Same goes for bootstrap which can be identified via it's framework's classes, or Angular.

So, you might have to dig into the HTML of the page to look around and find these indicators. Therefore, you also have to know the technologies and which features they offer and where they are stated on the HTML side and maybe JavaScript side. In general, digging into the JavaScripts defined in the header also offers insights if bootstrap, Angular, or Vue are used.

To get the info soley via the URL will not work.

Comment: I uess you misunderstood me, I just wanna learn web service not web page. Classical xml, web api json etc.

Comment: This is also highly dependent on the CMS how they work. E.g. how headless CMS forward their backend infos to a frontend or receive inputs. The APIs data format depends on the tech used.